# why php code sendmail is not sending activation-link to an email address?

Tags: php, mysql, sendmail

For email activation I'm using php *Sendmail* code.

I'm not using any 'Smtp or Php mailer function' but using a 'variable'. Whenever I attach a subdomain name with my activation link it didn't work and no mail is send. But when i attach a domain name with my activation link it work and it send a mail. What may be the reason that subdomain name is not sending mail and same code but just changing subdomain name into domain name works fine and send mail. why?

This is my code :

```
$to=$email;
$subject="Your confirmation link here";
$header="from: Meet Your Love<your email>";
$message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
$message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
$message.="http://meetyourlove.2fh.co/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

On third $message  you can see my subdomain name from *2freewebhosting* which is attach with `confirmation.php` which works for activating an email address but this subdomain link is not letting me to send an activation link in users email address. when i changed any domain name in it then it send mail what may be the reason??What is the best way to solve this problem? What should we exactly put a link which should be before `/confirmation.php`???

Please help me..!

Comment: why your are not using php mailer?

Comment: I'm new for it is there any idea how to make one?

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
      $from="katrinakaif@love.com";
      $to ="yourmail@gmail.com";
      $confirm_code="13";
      $message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
      $message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
      $message.="http://meetyourlove.2fh.co/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";

       $subject="test";
       $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
       $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
       $headers .= 'From:'.$from . "\r\n";

     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: can you tell me ashok sri what should be there exactly before ______________/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code and why???